# How to use variable in LIKE condition?

Tags: sql, toad

currently i am using the following query in TOAD,

```
DEFINE @name char(6);
SET @name = 'Ronie'+'%';
select * from employee where name like @name;
```

It is giving a "missing expression"
I am using TOAD for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

I'm hopeful this works

```
DEFINE NAME = "Ronie%" (CHAR);
select * from employee where name like '&&name';
```

Comment: I tested and it works with Oracle.  Thank you - I did not know this syntax, and it is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is here: not `'Ronie'+'%'` but `'Ronie'||'%'`